# IE Opacity and special characters

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, special-characters, opacity

I have a block element (div) that holds a couple of nested elements, all content is text. I use jQuery to fadeIn() and fadeOut() on mouseOver. Works okay in all browsers except for Internet Explorer (I tested in 7 and 8 so far), which fades all the text except for two special characters in the text: ← (left arrow) and → (right arrow)
Already tried `zoom: 1;` in the CSS to trigger `hasLayout` and the `element.filters[0].enabled = false;` thing.
Anyone?

Comment: Nothing fancy to it:
`$(".image-details").hover(
function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast",1,function(){
if (!!this.style.filter) this.style.removeAttribute("filter");
})
},
function(){
$(this).fadeTo("fast",.001)
});`

Answer (score 1):

Found the bug: had `position:relative` and `top:-1px` applied to the arrows span to shift it up a notch. Removed those attributes, now it works.
Still, too bad the alpha filter breaks on inline elements with position:relative.